# aspose convert pdf to excel as temporary file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aspose

The question is rather simple. I am using the aspose library to convert a pdf file to excel. The excel file is subsequently written to the database and this generated excel file is not needed in the future.

My method:

```
public void main(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

        InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream();

        Document document = new Document(inputStream);

        ExcelSaveOptions options = new ExcelSaveOptions();

        options.setFormat(ExcelSaveOptions.ExcelFormat.XLSX);

        document.save("newExcelFile.xlsx", options);
    }
```

In this method, the file is saved to the root folder of the project (if it is running locally). How can I not store this file, but make it temporary? My question is that this project is located on the server, and I would not like to create directories specifically for this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Document.save()` method has an overload for saving to an `OutputStream` ([See here for the API reference](https://reference.aspose.com/pdf/java/com.aspose.pdf/document/#save-java.io.OutputStream-com.aspose.pdf.SaveOptions-)).

Given that you can store the result to anything that implements an `OutputStream`, you can provide any implementation that you want - one useful option might be to use `ByteArrayOutputStream` to store the result in memory, or possibly - just use `Files.createTempFile()` and create a `FileOutputStream` for that.

For example, your code may be rewritten thus:

```java
public byte[] convertToExcel(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream();
    Document document = new Document(inputStream);
    ExcelSaveOptions options = new ExcelSaveOptions();
    options.setFormat(ExcelSaveOptions.ExcelFormat.XLSX);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    document.save(baos, options);
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you how you would correct my method, according to your recommendations

Comment: @Alexander I added an example for you.